# Synchronized Block inside the run method

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronized

Does using a synchronized block inside the run method makes any sense? I thought it does, as long as I'm using a relevant lock, not the instance of Runnable containing this run method. Reading the answers to similar questions on stackoverflow seemed to confirm this. I tried to write some simple code to test it and the synchronized block inside the run method doesn't prevent from data corruption:

```
public class Test {

    public Test() {
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            es.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        sum += 1;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        es.shutdown();
        while(!es.isTerminated()) {
        }
    }
    private int sum = 0;
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        System.out.println(t.sum);
    }
}
```

Why this code generates incorrect results? Is this because the synchronized block or some other mistake? I feel like I'm missing something basic here.

Comment: You are doing everything right, [and it works correctly](http://ideone.com/XdaXCm).

Comment: I think you might get bit by the Java memory model.

Comment: Which JRE are you using?

Comment: Weird, I've been getting random results between 900 and 1000.

Comment: You might be printing the sum before Test's run method completes.

Comment: Use `es.submit()` and have main run `.get()` on the returned future, **then** print the sum.

Comment: But I put while(!es.isTerminated()) that should prevent printing before completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible your executor encounters some sort of unexpected error. If that happens you won't know it because you are not getting any return value to check.

Try switching to [submit() instead](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.lang.Runnable%29) of execute() and store a list of [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) instances the Executor gives you. If the final sum is less than 1000, iterate the futures and get() each one. If an exception is raised you'll see what happened with that particular runnable task.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from your simple example, which looks OK, you should be careful with synchronization in Runnables to prevent them from blocking each other when one Runnable waits for some resource to be released only by another Runnable later in the queue that has not started yet and never will since the current waiting Runnable must finish first.

With enough worker Threads executing the jobs this is less likely to occur, though.